# c++ MPI_Bcast class

Tags: c++, mpi

I have a problem using MPI_Bcast. One processor initialize the class and then has to send it to the others. This is my class:

```
class A{

private:

unsigned rows, cols;
std::vector<int> elem;

public:

//default costructor
A(): rows(1), cols(1), elem(1,0){
}

//costructor
A(unsigned r, unsigned c):
rows(r), cols(c){
    elem.resize(rows*cols);
    for(unsigned i=0; i<rows*cols; i++)
        elem[i]=i+1;
}

//return the address of an element
int* give_address(unsigned i){
    return &elem[i];
}

//destructor
~A(){}

};
```

This is what I do in the main:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){

MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);

int rank, np;
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&rank);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&np);

A a;

if(np==1){

    std::cout<< "Only one!" << std::endl;

}else{

    if(rank==0){
        a=A(3,3);
    }

    MPI_Bcast(a.give_address(0),3*3,MPI_INT,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);

}

MPI_Finalize();

return 0;

}
```

However Bcast doesn't work and a segmentation fault is given! I don't know where is the problem...

Comment: I don't know what is it...

Comment: well now is a good time to learn

Comment: Is correct the way I use the method give_address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the processor rank is not 0, then the matrix a has a size 1x1. The buffer of processors 1,2,3... cannot fit all the data broadcasted by processor 0. You have to initialize a to be of the proper size also on the other processors.

Edit: to be more clear, the array pointed by a.give_address(0) on the receiving processors MUST be of AT LEAST size count (where count is 3*3 in your case).